# Calculate mean value of two objects

Tags: r, mean

Let's say we have two objects at the beginning:

```
a <- c(2,4,6)
b <- 8
```

If we apply the mean() function in each of them we get this:

```
> mean(a)
[1] 4
> mean(b)
[1] 8
```

... which is absolutely normal.

If I create a new object merging a and b...

```
c <- c(2,4,6,8)
```

and calculate its mean...

```
> mean(c)
[1] 5
```

... we get 5, which is the expected value.

However, I would like to calculate the mean value of both objects at the same time. I tried this way:

```
> mean(a,b)
[1] 4
```

As we can see, its value differs from the expected correct value (5). What am I missing?

Comment: `mean(c(a, b))`?

Comment: Use `c` to concatenate vectors; `mean(c(a,b))`

Comment: That's exactly what was missing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned, the correct solution is to concatenate the vectors before passing them to `mean`:

```
mean(c(a, b))
```

The reason that your original code gives a wrong result is due to what `mean`’s second argument is:

```
 ## Default S3 method:
 mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)
```

So when calling `mean` with two numeric arguments, the second one is passed as the `trim` argument, which, in turn, controls [how much trimming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean) is to be done. In your case, `8` causes the function to simply return the median (meaningful values for `trim` would be fractions between 0 and 0.5).

Answer (score 0):

If you print the argument `a,b` that you are feeding into the `mean` function, you will see that only `a` prints:
`print(a,b)
[1] 2 4 6`

So `mean(a,b)` only provides the mean of `a`. 
`mean(c(a,b))` will produce the expected answer of 5.

Comment: and if you type `cat(a,b)` what happens ?

Comment: I don't think this is the correct logic. It's about the arguments to `mean`. Compare with `sum(a, b)`.