# Saving code by avoid writing consecutive numbers in R

Tags: r

Suppose we have these objects:

```
distM_ref1_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref1$x, distM_ref1$y))
distM_ref2_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref2$x, distM_ref2$y))
distM_ref3_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref3$x, distM_ref3$y))
distM_ref4_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref4$x, distM_ref4$y))
distM_ref5_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref5$x, distM_ref5$y))
distM_ref6_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref6$x, distM_ref6$y))
distM_ref7_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref7$x, distM_ref7$y))
distM_ref8_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref8$x, distM_ref8$y))
distM_ref9_matrix <- dist(cbind(distM_ref9$x, distM_ref9$y))
```

I have two questions:

1. How can I save code by creating all these objects automatically with a single line? Consider I do have tons of equivalent objects, not only 9 as in the example.
2. How can I calculate the [mean value of all these objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810286/calculate-mean-value-of-two-objects/48810510#48810510) at the same time?

I think that the answer for the second question would be somehow like this code:

```
mean(c(distM_ref[1:9]_matrix))
```

Comment: You could store your data as a list. Each matrix you can assign using  `distM_matrix[[i]]`, where is  `i`   your number. This will help in all further calculations.

Comment: The solution to this requires that you go all the way back to when you created all the `distM_ref1` etc objects and instead put them all in a single list. In general, you want to avoid creating separate objects like `obj1`, `obj2`, etc. It's very inefficient. Put them in a list.

Comment: Variables should not have indexes in the name. That just makes things hard to work with. If you have an indexed collection of something, store those values in a list (or vector). it makes it way easier to iterate over the values. So like joran said, take a step back to where you created all those variables in the first place. There is probably a more R-like way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, I've never worked with lists, so an example on how to do it with the data shown above would significantly help.